# pactl works in userspace not as root on i3

Tags: pulseaudio, i3

I am running i3wm and am setting up keybindings for it. I would like to use a set of keybindings to control the volume of my system.

I have set a key to: `exec pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle`.

Pressing this key has no effect. I can however run `pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle` in my terminal and it works. However when run as root (`sudo pactl ...`) it fails with:

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

However it acts as expected when called as a user.

I am running Arch Linux.

Comment: Pulseaudio by default runs as the logged in user, so it will only react to `pactl` as the logged in user (unless you give other users permissions). The more interesting question is why your i3wm is running as root, usually the WM should also run as the user who is connected to X. If you run your WM this way (as I do), pulseaudio keybindings will just work out of the box.

Comment: How are you starting `i3`? Even if it's not running as root, it needs to have e.g. `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in its environment so that `pactl` can find the PulseAudio server socket.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to have `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in the environment and identify yourself as the normal user.

```
sudo -u '#1000' XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle
```

Both instances of `1000` should be substituted with the normal user ID. If you do not know it, run `id -u` as the normal user.