# Root does not have access to Master control

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-volume, acpid

TL;DR: root doesn't have access to the `Master` controls on ALSA

### My problem

I cannot control volume with my keyboard

### The diagnostics I have done

- `journalctl -f` reveals the error `amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master', 0`
- `amixer` works fine if I run it from the terminal

This leads me to believe that it's a permission problem

### My environment

- My acpid config file for volume down looks like this:

```
events=button/volumedown
action=amixer set Master
```

- I dual-boot Arch Linux and Windows.
- I used to use xfce but uninstalled it in favour of dwm/lxde depending on my mood.
- I use PulseAudio for bluetooth support.

### What I have tried so far

- Using doas (like sudo)

  - Exactly the same error at `journalctl -f`, except that there's a line before that says `root ran command amixer set Master 5- as vince from /` (my username is vince)
- Using `pactl`

  - Same problem

### What I hope for from a solution

- It gives root access to the `Master` controls
- I'd rather not rely on `sudo` or `doas` because that doesn't really scale to multiple users (I'm willing to use it as a temporary workaround though)
- Works for both the console and `X`
- It doesn't have to work for all users but I'd prefer it if it did

(It's okay if an answer doesn't fulfill all of these, I just want to use my volume keys)

Answer (score 0):

> I use PulseAudio for bluetooth support.

If you run Pulseaudio, please use the Pulseaudio API for volume settings (or script it via `pacmd` or `pactl`).

Pulseaudio provides a compatibility layer for ALSA that include this "Master" control, but that gets mapped to Pulseaudio volume settings.

Also read up on [system-wide](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/) Pulseaudio vs. per-user Pulseaudio. The latter is the default, and means that any user different from the logged-in user who started Pulseaudio cannot access Pulseaudio, and that includes root.

So your problem isn't an ALSA problem: Under ALSA only you wouldn't have a generic "Master" control (though most **audio cards** do have one), and under ALSA only it's no problem for root to access it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It didn't solve my problem, but it led me on the right path, as I highlighted in the answer I have now posted

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem satisfactorily. As I suspected, `root` cannot access my user's sink because of pulseaudio. The answer from @dirkt prompted me to look for solutions for pulseaudio, and the solution is highlighted here: [pactl works in userspace not as root on i3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457946/pactl-works-in-userspace-not-as-root-on-i3).

Since I'm using `doas`, I had to add `setenv {XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000}` to `doas.conf`. Then I edited my acpid config files to look like this:

```
event=button/volumedown
action=doas -u vince pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5%%
```

A better solution might be to use system-wide pulseaudio, as suggested by @dikrt's answer, but this is the solution I have so far

Comment: The correct solution to have the window manager react on volume button events is actually to use `pactl` etc. as non-root (if done this on my laptop, though for fvwm, not i3). Also, the "default sink" may not work like you think it does.